# How to validate a calculated column on an ADO.NET DataTable

Tags: winforms, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

According to MS, calculated columns (AKA expression columns) don't raise any DataTable events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401%28v=vs.80%29.aspx,

This makes it impossible to use the DataTable.ColumnChanging event to validate the value of such column by using the technique documented at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171930%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

I'd like to know if someone has thought of a way to add some form of validation to such calculated columns so that it will work with the standard ErrorProvider control on a Windows Form ?

Thank you

Comment: Couldn't you just use a DataView of the datatable and use the ListChanged property?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `bindingsource`:

```
private void Asignar_Columna_Balance()
{      


    if (cataciones_BindingSource.Current == null) return;
    var _fila_Actual = ((cataciones_BindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Row as DataSet_SKNCC_Reportes.REPORTE_CATACIONESRow);

    if ((cataciones_BindingSource.Current as DataRowView).IsNew)
        _fila_Actual["BALANCE"] = (_fila_Actual.AROMA + _fila_Actual.ACIDEZ + _fila_Actual.CUERPO + _fila_Actual.SABOR).ToString();
    else
    {
        //FORCE REBINDING!!! PARA QUE FUNCIONE AL EDITAR UN BINDINGDOURCE!!!! 
        cataciones_Tabla_Lote.Columns["BALANCE"].Expression = null;                
        cataciones_Tabla_Lote.Columns["BALANCE"].Expression = "Aroma + Acidez + Cuerpo + Sabor";
    }

    //balance_Mask.Text = (_fila_Actual.AROMA + _fila_Actual.ACIDEZ + _fila_Actual.CUERPO + _fila_Actual.SABOR).ToString();
}
```